# Verilog always block triggers misbehaving

Tags: verilog

I have an always block that involves a switch and a key. When I have only the key in the sensitivity list, it behaves fine (only executes the code once then exits the block). When I add the switch to the sensitivity list, it goes crazy and seems to loop indefinitely while I'm holding the key down, even though I only have it trigger on negedge of the key press.

I'm trying to implement a counter that only increments once on each key press.

Here is the working code with only the key in the sensitivity list (sw[1] is to indicate whether it is counting up or down):

```
always @ (negedge key[2]) begin
  if (~key[2]) 
      begin
        if (sw[1] == 0) begin
          if (p3ctr == 15) p3ctr = 0;
          else p3ctr = p3ctr + 1;
        end
        else if (sw[1] == 1) begin
          if (p3ctr == 0) p3ctr = 15;
          else p3ctr = p3ctr - 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the broken code (I'm using sw[7] to reset the counter when it gets switched up. This code loops indefinitely while key[2] is held down)

```
always @ (negedge key[2] or posedge sw[7]) begin
  if (~key[2]) 
      begin
        if (sw[1] == 0) begin
          if (p3ctr == 15) p3ctr = 0;
          else p3ctr = p3ctr + 1;
        end
        else if (sw[1] == 1) begin
          if (p3ctr == 0) p3ctr = 15;
          else p3ctr = p3ctr - 1;
        end
    end
  else begin
    p3ctr = 0;
  end
end
```

I thought the code in an always block only gets executed once when a signal in the sensitivity list changes, but apparently that isn't the case.

Any idea how I can get this code to execute only once on each key press so the counter behaves properly?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "goes crazy"? Does this happen in simulation as well? You are performing simulations, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is being seen when running on a FPGA; a pure simulation would appear fine. The synthesis tool is assuming the first `if` is asynchronous logic and the `else` condition is treated as synchronous logic as that is the proper coding style. In the provided code the first condition is `if (~key[2])` which means the synthesis tool will treat `negedge key[2]` as active low asynchronous logic. Start with the reset condition `if (sw[7])` and you should get the desired result.

```
always @ (negedge key[2] or posedge sw[7]) begin
  if (sw[7]) begin
    p3ctr <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    if (sw[1] == 0) begin
      if (p3ctr == 15) p3ctr <= 0;
      else p3ctr <= p3ctr + 1;
    end
    else if (sw[1] == 1) begin
      if (p3ctr == 0) p3ctr <= 15;
      else p3ctr <= p3ctr - 1;
    end
  end
end
```

Note: best practice to use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) with flops. Blocking assignment (`=`) is for combination logic.